# SSRS 2008: Why does a declared query variable show in the "Define Query Parameters" window?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, bids

I'm having trouble creating a dataset in Reporting Services 2008. Here's the query I want to use (generic-ized for public consumption):

```
Declare @PersonID as int
set @PersonID = (select top 1 personID from People where name = @PersonName)

select (some columns)
from [otherTable]
where personID = @PersonID
```

I only have one input parameter: `@PersonName`. However, Studio 2008 seems to think `@PersonID` *also* needs a value in the "Define Query Parameters" window. So when I try to only enter a value for `@PersonName`, it gives me the "This variable has already been defined".

I'm passing `@PersonName` because I need to display a human-readable list of the people to select from a dropdown as the only user-facing parameter to the report. I realize I could do a subquery and forget the variable in the above example, but my real query is much larger/uglier, and I can't exactly add indices to the data tables, so I'd like to limit the table scans.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new dataset to use with your parameter.

First, a new dataset with a query of

```
SELECT PersonID, PersonName FROM People
```

Then, on your report parameter (I'm changing the name to *Person* for clarity), in the Available Values section, switch it to "Get values from a query". Select your new dataset, and set the Value field to PersonID and the Label field to PersonName.

Finally, set your main dataset's @PersonID parameter to be the report parameter [@Person].

This way, you can show the list, but still work off of the ID.  No need for the PersonName report parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @PersonName char(20) 

select (some columns)
from  [otherTable] 
join  [People]
  on  [otherTable].[personID] = [People].[personID]
where [People].[name] = @PersonName
```

Give it a try before you assume it is going have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not turn the query into a stored procedure?  From my experience, stored procs provide better performance (watch out for parameter sniffing though) as well as reusability.

edit:

And it would def eliminate your issue.